# How to add Select Option values to Enumerable.Range SelectList

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

How do I add option values to this `SelectList`

**Controller:**

`model.BeginMonthList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 12), beginMonth);`

**View:**

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BeginMonth, Model.BeginMonthList, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })`

This is how the HTML looks right now (no values in `<option>` tag):

```
<select class="form-control input-sm valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field BeginMonth must be a number." id="BeginMonth" name="BeginMonth"><option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option selected="selected">11</option>
<option>12</option>
</select>
```

Basically would like to add values that are same as the text.

Comment: Why? When the `value` attribute is omitted, then the value of the text is submitted when you submit (but you can of course create a new `List<SelectListItem>` and set the `Value` and `Text` properties)

Comment: edge is having issues. chrome/ff work just fine.

Comment: What is the issue? (is it not submitting the selected value, or is it something related to a script?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Edge is appending a zero to the selected text. For instance if I select 3, it sends 30 (via GET form). Chrome or Firefox don't do that.

Comment: I created [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UjkUeT) and ran it in Chrome, FireFox and Edge. In all cases, the correct value was returned (3, not 30), so I cannot duplicate what you are claiming.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you please check this donetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/chPLOM. Bad thing is you cannot see the browser query string. but i can duplicate the issue by copying that dotnetfiddle into a new MVC app in Visual Studio, so that i can see the actual query string being posted. on the form, click Go, then change a month, again click Go, and compare the results in Edge and FF.

Comment: I have done that, and the results are exactly the same in all browsers - there is no zero appended to the selected value (and tested IE as well). But your controller code does not make much sense - it needs parameters `int? beginMonth, int? beginYear, ...` etc to bind to the query string values when you submit the form

Comment: @StephenMuecke the controller is simplified. the int? month/year has default values in case they're missing from query string.

Comment: Yes, but when you submit, the values are not bound to anything and when you return the view, your just displaying the default values again, not the values the user selected

Comment: like i said it's simplified to the point that i can reproduce the issue. even if it looks like a dumb controller.

Comment: Well I cannot reproduce what you claiming. If I select 3 for the BeginMonth, the query string value is `...&BeginMonth=3&...` in all browsers (not 30)

Comment: wish you could see live on my desktop. its right in your face. edge does it but chrome/FF dont. i just want to find out what im doing wrong to irk edge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178495/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-joym8).